# Propel: how do i retrieve all elements from database by one in a loop?

Tags: php, propel

i try to do as follows:

```
$q = PhotographerQuery::create();
$photographer = $q->limit(1)->find();

while ($photographer) {
    $id = $photographer->getId();
    echo "$id {$photographer->getName()}\n";

    // do something - no idea what ... limit() supports only one parameter to
    // specify quontity of elements to be fetched
    $photographer = $q->limit(1)->somethingElse()->find();
}
```

How do I modify it to make this script up and running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `offset` but I honestly doubt that you really want it that way. For such use cases we have on-Demand-hydration: http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#collections-and-on-demand-hydration

Comment: thanks! this is useful - dindn't know about hydration!